# UITextView text give small gap between each word in middle of text

Tags: ios, objective-c, fonts, uitextview

Team,

I have UITextView added content of text,  with font family avinar roma, I noticed there is small gap in between each word which was not consistent.  How to avoid the small gap in textview text for each word.

[image]

```
    descriptionTextView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, titlelabel.frame.origin.y + titlelabel.frame.size.height + 5, view.frame.size.width - 40, view.frame.size.height - 150)];
    descriptionTextView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    descriptionTextView.textColor = MH_PANTONE_444;
    descriptionTextView.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    descriptionTextView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:MH_FONT_AVENIRROMAN size:MH_SCREEN_HEIGHT/48];
    descriptionTextView.text = [descriptionArray objectAtIndex:index];
    descriptionTextView.editable = NO;
    descriptionTextView.scrollEnabled = NO;
    descriptionTextView.selectable = YES;
    descriptionTextView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeAll;
```

Please have image attached above 
University Medical Center, is not same gap with remaining text.

Comment: Please provide screen shot for this.

Comment: The text looks rather "justified" than "centered"

Comment: @d.felber In both cases "Justified" or "Centered" it will be give gap's to another text.  How to avoid the Gaps in UITextView Text.

Comment: @d.felber In my case i need to use Justified for NSAlignment.

Comment: @kiran If your text looks exactly like in your example when using "center" something is very very wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the `hyphenationFactor` should fix your problem. But you have to use `NSAttributedString` instead of plain text:

```
UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName: MH_FONT_AVENIRROMAN size: MH_SCREEN_HEIGHT/48];
NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
paragraphStyle.hyphenationFactor = 1.0;

NSDictionary *attributes = @{ NSFontAttributeName:font,
                              NSForegroundColorAttributeName: MH_PANTONE_444;
                              NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle };

NSMutableAttributedString *attributedText = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString: [descriptionArray objectAtIndex:index]
                                                                                   attributes: attributes];

descriptionTextView.attributedText = attributedText;
```

https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/nsmutableparagraphstyle/1535553-hyphenationfactor

You may have to adjust the `hyphenationFactor` until you get the result you want. (0.0-1.0)

Comment: Its work pretty good but, at the end of sentance it try to make contiue with "-" symbol indicator.  How to avoid "-" the whole part move to next line

Comment: when using hyphenation (separation of syllables) some words that are too long for your line may get separated by an hyphen ("-")
If you don't want that you may need to use `NSTextAlignmentLeft`.
When you don't allow breaking up the words using hyphens you get the result as described in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the same issue by setting the `leftView` property of the `UITextField` to be an empty view with the size of the padding as desired:

```
UIView *paddingView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 5, 20)];
textView.leftView = paddingView;
textView.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had also face an issue of text alignment with custom fonts in iOS application, and that was with vertical alignment. I guess this is because of the custom font you are using in your application. But luckily there is a solution.

Every font file have some configurations about display the letter. One of the property is `minLeftSideBearing` for left spacing and `minRightSideBearing` for right spacing. I guess by changing them you can solve this spacing issue.

Follow the following link to check how to change this properties.
http://www.andyyardley.com/2012/04/24/custom-ios-fonts-and-how-to-fix-the-vertical-position-problem/

And as mention in above blog you need to install font tool. That you can download from following link.

https://developer.apple.com/download/more/?=font

Hope this might help you.

Thanks, Jay.